# How to get latitude and longitude while there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, maps, core-location

I have an app that takes your location and print it on a label. But i have a problem when there has not internet connection the latitude and longitude is not showing.Here is my code.Any solution to get latitude and longitude offline ?.Sorry for my language.

```
@IBOutlet weak var latitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Longitude: UILabel!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func mapsPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    self.locationsManager()
}

func locationsManager(){
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR:" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let pm = placemarks?.first {
            self.saveLatitudeLongitude(pm)
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
        else {
            print("Error with data")
        }
    })
}

func saveLatitudeLongitude(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
    //  self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.latitude.text = String(placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)
    self.Longitude.text = String(placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because of the call of the reverse geocoder. The reverse geocoding requires an internet connection. But if you only need latitude and longitude, using reverse geocoder is not necessary. The coordinates should be available in the location from `didUpdateLocations`.

Off the top of my head (no access to Xcode):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations.first?.coordinates)
}
```